# How to open .exe files from C# one by one?

Tags: c#, exe

I need to open EXE files one by one, but I do not know how to do it. I tried:

```
Process.Start("V:\\RIMI_Change_Cards.exe");
Process.Start("V:\\RIMI_Client_Information.exe");
Process.Start("V:\\E_Registration_Trace.exe");
```

But it opens together. What command do I need?

Comment: Do you need to wait for them to do something? Close?

Comment: Yes, then one exe finish, it has close, and then start another, but i found answer, so thank you :)